# Javascript, unexpected token =>

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I get the following error when trying to write a javascript function to deploy to firebase:

> Parsing error: Unexpected token =>

at the code:

```js
exports.sendFriendRequest = functions.firestore.document("requests/{rUid}").
onWrite(async (event) => {
    const userId1 = event.after.get("userId1");
    const userId2 = event.after.get("userId2");
    let userName1 = await admin.firestore().doc("users/${userId1}/name").get();
    console.log(userName1);

    const title = "New friend request";
    const content = "${userName1} wants to be your friend";
    console.log(content);

    let user2 = await admin.firestore().doc("users/${userId2}").get();
    let fcmToken = user2.get("fcm");

    // let userDoc = await admin.firestore().doc('users/${uid}').get();
    // let fcmToken = userDoc.get('fcm');

    var message = {
        notification: {
            title: title,
            body: content,
        },
        token: fcmToken,
    }

    let response = await admin.messaging().send(message);
    console.log(response);
});
```

All the parantheses match and my node version is 14.16.1. I don t know why I get this, any ideas?
I uploaded an image below with the code.

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Fq0G.png)

Comment: Hope this [answer](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/319) helps

Comment: Unrelated but you need to use backticks `\`` to create [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). `${}` substitutions will not work with quotes `"`

Comment: you might have lesser version of node in firebase cloud, similar issue can be found [here](https://www.javaer101.com/en/article/11171950.html)

Comment: Thank you, guys! Thank you @adiga for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current configuration, ESLint doesn't understand what `async`/`await` syntax is.

You'll need to open up your `.eslintrc.js` (or `.eslintrc.*`) file, and make sure that `ecmaVersion` is **at least** version 8 (ES2017). See the [docs](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/language-options#specifying-parser-options) for more information.

```js
// for .eslintrc.js
module.exports = {
  /* ... other settings ... */
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 8,
    /* ... other settings ... */
  },
  /* ... other settings ... */
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This was the answer. I already tried that but I don't why it did not work back then.